# SSL certificate not verified Error on Android kitkat version

Tags: android, apache, google-chrome, ssl, android-4.4-kitkat

I have SSL verified website, which is successfully verified by third party vendor.
And it working fine without any warning/errors in other OS like windows, chrome browser

When I am trying to open it from mobile with KitKat version It show below error code

```
Error Code : NET:: ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same error: app requesting https working fine on all platforms and versions except old android 4.4 - problem was conflicting Comodo root certificates on IIS server machine.

The main issue is that i had two certificates chains on remote:

- a. Comodo -> Comodo -> your site certificate
- b. AddTrust -> Comodo ->
  your site certificate

That is not a problem for everyone but the old Android who (now just a bit of humor) thinks its a conflict and a sign of something evil so your site is not trusted.
I followed the path from https://stackoverflow.com/a/46135138/7149454, my thanks and credits, so finally:

1. On remote windows open MMC: **search** "certificates", open **Manage computer certificates**.
2. open **Trusted Root Certification Authorities** delete completely comodo unique certificate so there's no comodo at all in this section. We dont need it as your Comodo intermediate certificate need to be verified by AddTrust and not this one.
3. open **Intermediate Certification Authorities** delete 1 of 2 comodo certificate issued to Comodo RSA Certification Authority, leave only one issued by AddTrust, delete one issued by Comodo itself.
4. **REBOOT** Now you have the logic chain from AddTrust -> Comodo ->
   your site certificate.