# Suddenly getting "Error: TrustFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.)" on my Xamarin Android app

Tags: android, ssl, xamarin, ssl-certificate

Just out of the blue, my app started getting this error when making calls to a REST API via https. I was working on a mod that added an Intent to handle opening files of a certain file extension but I doubt that that was the cause.

Instead, the problem is similar to this one:
[Invalid certificate received from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43815536/invalid-certificate-received-from-server)

My cert is also by Comodo and has been installed since April of this year. The solution of disabling the COMODO RSA Certification Authority did not work.

The server is a VPS that the host underwent a hardware upgrade during the time that this error started to appear but I'm also not sure that that would be the reason since the browser shows SSL as fine and the iOS version of the app is also working fine.

The code in the app that makes the call to the server is in a utility class and I did not change that code at all. The minor change that I did was to add an intent which I then removed and the error is still there.

Here are the error messages including the inner exceptions and the stack trace:

```
System.Net.WebExceptionStatus.TrustFailure

ex.InnerException.Message - The authentication or decryption has failed.

ex.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException.Message - Invalid certificate received from server. Error code: 0xffffffff800b010b

ex.InnerException.InnerException.StackTrace
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.EndReceiveRecord (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0003a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/RecordProtocol.cs:430 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.SafeEndReceiveRecord (System.IAsyncResult ar, System.Boolean ignoreEmpty) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/SslClientStream.cs:256 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.NegotiateAsyncWorker (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00071] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/SslClientStream.cs:418 

ex.InnerException.StackTrace
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.EndRead (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00051] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/SslStreamBase.cs:883 
  at Mono.Net.Security.Private.LegacySslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/LegacySslStream.cs:475 
  at Mono.Net.Security.Private.LegacySslStream.AuthenticateAsClient (System.String targetHost, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, System.Boolean checkCertificateRevocation) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/LegacySslStream.cs:445 
  at Mono.Net.Security.MonoTlsStream.CreateStream (System.Byte[] buffer) [0x0004e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/MonoTlsStream.cs:106
```

I'm using the standard port 443. I checked the bindings and there are no issues, it says that the cert is 'ok' when I view the certification path status.

I am getting the error when using an actual device, not an emulator.

Any help is appreciated.

***** update

I called Comodo's support and found out the issue is with Android's certificate store not being up to date and using the old legacy SHA. So the certification path 2 was coming back to the client with a 'Extra Download' status. There supposedly is a cert named 'COMODO RSA Certification Authority' in my server expiring in 2036 that interferes with 'COMODO RSA Certification Authority' intermediate certificate expiring in 2020. Here are the details of that cert:

[Root] Comodo RSA Certification Authority (SHA-2)
Serial Number: 4c:aa:f9:ca:db:63:6f:e0:1f:f7:4e:d8:5b:03:86:9d
Issuer: C=GB, ST=Greater Manchester, L=Salford, O=COMODO CA Limited, CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
Validity (Expires) : Jan 18 23:59:59 2038 GMT

However, I couldn't find out in both local computer and current user. Since this is a VPS/virtual machine, the problem may be that the host machine may be adding this in the virtual network communication/response back to the client. The problem now is that the hosting company doesn't want to disable the cert in the host machine.

Comment: It might be helpful if you provide the domain you are trying to access so that one could actually check the state of the certificate and to help you find the cause of the problem. There are a variety of configuration changes which could be done in the context of the hardware upgrade which might affect some TLS clients but not others, like a requirement to use SNI or missing chain certificates.

Comment: What does SSL checker say about the certificate?  https://www.sslchecker.com/sslchecker

Comment: Ken, thank you for mentioning sslchecker.com - I entered my site domain and says "Vendor signed: No - SSL is not trusted' and shows 3 of the certs in the chain are missing: COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA, COMODO RSA Certification Authority and AddTrust External CA Root. I downloaded all three of them from Comodo's support website (https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/comodo/Knowledgebase/Article/View/979/108/domain-validation-sha-2) & imported them into the server then checked sslchecker again, but it still says the same thing. I even rebooted the website and app pool in IIS.

Comment: Steffen, thank you for your comment. Can you provide some links to what these hardware upgrades are so I can mention them to my hosting. As to my domain, I prefer not to post it especially with an existing vulnerability as this is.

Comment: I looked at the cert from inside IIS > Edit Site Bindings > View Certificate and in the Certification Path tab it shows all four certs are 'Ok' and show them all in a descending parent/child chain. I don't know how to post images here but if that helps I can find out how.

Comment: Steffen, could it be that Certificate Services was reconfigured during the hardware upgrade? My site is actually running on a virtual private server (VPS) inside a host machine, so I don't think anything got reconfigured inside my VM.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working. As I mentioned in my update above, the issue is with Android's certificate store not being up to date and using the old legacy SHA. So the certification path 2 was coming back to the client with a 'Extra Download' status. There is a cert named 'COMODO RSA Certification Authority' in expiring in 2036 that interferes with 'COMODO RSA Certification Authority' intermediate certificate expiring in 2020. I had already deleted it that's why I couldn't find it anymore.

The fix is to find & disable or delete this cert, replace it with new certs downloaded from Comodo's website, and rebooting the machine.

Here are the details of the cert to disable/delete:

[Root] Comodo RSA Certification Authority (SHA-2)

Serial Number: 4c:aa:f9:ca:db:63:6f:e0:1f:f7:4e:d8:5b:03:86:9d

Issuer: C=GB, ST=Greater Manchester, L=Salford, O=COMODO CA Limited, CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority

Validity (Expires) : Jan 18 23:59:59 2038 GMT

The new certs are:

comodorsadomainvalidationsecureserverca.crt

comodorsaaddtrustca.crt

addtrustexternalcaroot.crt

I can't find the page where I downloaded all three from, the Comodo tech support rep helped me navigate to this page.

To disable the cert, go into Certification Manager from the MMC, right click to open, click on the Details tab, click on the Edit Properties button and in the Certificate Purposes area, choose the 'Disable for all purposes' radio option.

Import the new certs and reboot.

And instead of using SSLChecker, I recommend SSL Server Test by Qualys SSL Labs (https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html) as it's more accurate & detailed.

Comment: Thank you so much for the way to follow, created a similar answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51739444/7149454

Comment: Here they are https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/List/Index/71